# Названия тестов + нумерация в codeception

Tags: php, yii2, codeception

Не могу найти в документации имеется ли возможность в codeception делать нумерованный вывод тестов в консоль, а так же не могу найти как менять описания тестов, ниже видно, что Success login и Wrong login это имена методов класса ConsumerLoginCest

```
Powered by PHPUnit 6.2.4 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

Api_v1 Tests (2) -------------------------------------------
✔ ConsumerLoginCest: Success login (0.76s)
✔ ConsumerLoginCest: Wrong login (0.10s)
------------------------------------------------------------


Time: 1.13 seconds, Memory: 26.00MB

OK (2 tests, 13 assertions)
```

Хотелось бы иметь вот это

```
[1] ✔ ConsumerLoginCest: МОЕ КАСТОМНОЕ ОПИСАНИЕ (0.76s)
[2] ✔ ConsumerLoginCest: МОЕ КАСТОМНОЕ ОПИСАНИЕ (0.10s)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В каждом тесте можно писать что-то свое для вывода в консоль.

```
/**
 * @param ApiTester $I
 */
public function checkEmpty(ApiTester $I): void
{
    $I->wantTo('-> Авторизация без логина/пароля');
    $I->sendPOST('login', []);
    $I->checkBadLoginRequest();
}
```

Если использовать провайдер данных, тогда каждый запуск теста с отдельным экземпляром данных будет пронумерован. Название метода провайдера необходимо указать в аннотации к методу теста.

```
/**
* @dataProvider pageProvider
*/
public function staticPages(AcceptanceTester $I, \Codeception\Example $example)
{
    $I->amOnPage($example['url']);
    $I->see($example['title'], 'h1');
    $I->seeInTitle($example['title']);
}

/**
 * @return array
 */
protected function pageProvider()
{
    return [
        ['url'=>"/", 'title'=>"Welcome"],
        ['url'=>"/info", 'title'=>"Info"],
        ['url'=>"/about", 'title'=>"About Us"],
        ['url'=>"/contact", 'title'=>"Contact Us"]
    ];
}
```